# c# read 3 files at once, search string and display results

Tags: c#, file

I am working on a program that will open 3 files at once, search for a string (game name) and then display the results in a list box with the information from the 3 files.

So far I have this

```
    string gamesData;
    string salesData;
    string compData;
    string textBox;

    StreamReader gamesFile, salesFile, compFile;

    gamesFile = File.OpenText("game.dat");
    salesFile = File.OpenText("SalesNumbers.dat");
    compFile = File.OpenText("company.dat");

    textBox = searchTxtBox.Text;


   while (!gamesFile.EndOfStream)
   {
        if (searchTxtBox.Text != "")
        {
            if(searchTxtBox.Text.Trim() == gamesData)
            {
                string.Compare(textBox, gamesData);
                gamesData = gamesFile.ReadLine();
                salesData = salesFile.ReadLine();
                compData = compFile.ReadLine();
                listBoxGames.Items.Add(gamesData +"====" + salesData + "====" + compData);
            }

            else 
                if (microRb.Checked)
                  {                           
                compData = "ms";
                  }
            else
                if (eaRb.Checked)
                {
                    compData = "ea";

                }
                else
                    {
                        compData = "blz";
                    }

        }

    }

        salesFile.Close();
        gamesFile.Close();
        compFile.Close();
```

The program becomes non responsive when I click the search button I was wondering if someone to point me what I am doing wrong thank you.

Comment: what happens when you step through the code..? can you tell us where in the process it hangs..?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is multithreading / concurrency / parallel programming, and there are multiple ways to go about it...

So here's something to get you started.

```
string[] textFilePaths = new string[]{"games.dat", "SalesNumbers.dat", "company.dat"};
ConcurrentBag<string> bagOfStrings = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(textFilePaths, path => 
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    bagOfStrings.Add(text);
});

foreach(var text in bagOfStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine (text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates an infinite loop.  Your `while` loop won't stop until you get to the end of `gamesFile`.  But, the line where you actually *read* from `gamesFile` won't run, because it is surrounded by `if (searchTxtBox.Text.Trim() == gamesData)`.  Your `gamesData` variable is declared in the first few lines, but it hasn't been assigned a value yet, so it's null.  `searchTxtBox.Text.Trim()` does not equal null, so you never read from gamesFile.  So, you never get to the end of `gamesFile`, and your `while` loop runs forever.

A common idiom to read through the lines in a file is something like this:

```
while ((gamesData = gamesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // do something with gamesData here
}
```

That works because ReadLine returns null when it reaches the end of the file.  So, you could write something like:

```
while ((gamesData = gamesFile.ReadLine()) != null && (salesData = salesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
```